# Are there technical terms to describe this non-normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, likert, distribution-identification

This question is about visual inspection of normality. An example of my variable is shown below. This is aggregated Likert scale data (n = 2000). By visual inspection, the data has some sort of bell-shaped curve there but it appears staggered. (I am guessing this shape is due to the Likert scale restricting whole numbers as responses, so even when aggregated, the data do not appear as a continuous variable). When I run a Shapiro-Wilk normality test, the p-value is 1.069e-06 so it is definitely not a normal distribution.

I'm trying to understand whether the staggered shape is responsible for making the data non-normal? Are there technical terms to describe this shape?

Since this is aggregated Likert data, I won't be transforming it and will be running non-parametric tests. If this were another kind of data and I were prepared to process it further, what kind of processing might be used to "smooth out" the undulated parts?

[image]

Comment: It’s often informative to look at the empirical CDF, something like plot(x, ecdf(x)(x)) in R. That plot looks pretty normal to me. (I have tricked myself with “undulating”-looking histograms, only to find the CDF to match my expectation (often U(0,1) for p-values under the null hypothesis in a simulation).)

Comment: In addition to @Dave comments, try a qq-plot!

Comment: Is there any significance to the division separations aligning at 3.0 and being very slightly more than 0.2 wide?
¶ Also, the pattern of highs and lows seems to be mostly symmetric around the 4.7 mark, making it look like it *is* an artefact of the calculations and not representative of the data.

Comment: One plausible explanation for the "staggered" shape is that one discrete response, having around 10 equally spaced levels, has been included with a relatively high weight in a linear combination of responses to create these numbers.  That's worth understanding, but even then there is as yet no indication that a transformation is needed: for many purposes, these data are sufficiently symmetric and (on a large scale) unimodal to be considered consistent with the underlying assumptions of whatever procedure you're applying.